# What is the right way to combine internal auth along with B2C auth for the same Azure web app?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have an application web MVC that uses AAD to authenticate, But I need the same application to be used as B2C.

Is there any way to configure it or should I create a page for the user to choose by which directory to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to configure it or should I create a page for the user to choose by which directory to authenticate.

Based on my understanding, we need to provide a way to provide users to choose the identity data provider they want to authentication if the web app provide multiple identity data providers. For example, we can provide two buttons or a custom login page as you mentioned in above.

Here is a piece of custom code which provide users select the login way using two buttons from the code sample [here](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet.git).

_LoginPartial.cshtml(Add the UI to choose identity data provider):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign up", "SignUp", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "signUpLink" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign in", "SignIn", "Account", routeValues: new { b2c=false}, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign in B2C", "SignIn", "Account", routeValues: new { b2c = true }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
</ul>
```

Startup.Auth.cs(Provider two identity data providers)

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        // Configure OpenID Connect middleware for each policy
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignUpPolicyId));
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ProfilePolicyId));
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId));

        //config for normal azure ad
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "{AzureADClientId}",
                Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }

                }
            });
  }
```

AccountController.cs( Redirect to the identity data provider based on the choosing of users)

```
public void SignIn(bool b2c)
{
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (b2c)
            {
                // To execute a policy, you simply need to trigger an OWIN challenge.
                // You can indicate which policy to use by specifying the policy id as the AuthenticationType
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" }, Startup.SignInPolicyId);
            }
            else
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
}
```

Hope it helps.